# ReferenceError when I try to execute unit test using jest over a NGXS service facade [angular]

Tags: angular, jestjs, ngxs

I am trying to write some test in jest for a NGXS implementation, but in all the places where I am using the store, I am receiving the next error:

```
  ReferenceError: auth_models_1 is not defined

       5 | export class AuthSelectors{
       6 |     @Selector([AuthsState])
    >  7 |     static isAuth(state: AuthStateModel): Boolean {
         |                          ^
       8 |         return state.isAuth
       9 |     }
      10 |
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

I have a service facade that is in charge to connect the Store with the different components, and I have already do the respective imports for the store in the test file:

auth-facade.sercice.spec.ts

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { NgxsModule, Store } from '@ngxs/store';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthFacade } from './auth-facade.service';
import { User } from '../../../store/auth/auth.models';
import { AuthsState } from '../../../store/auth/auth.state';

describe('AuthFacade', () => {
  let authFacade: AuthFacade;
  let store: Store;

  const mockUser: User = {
    id: '1',
    email: 'testuser@test.com',
    language: 'en',
    name: 'Test User',
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [NgxsModule.forRoot([AuthsState])]
    });

    store = TestBed.inject(Store);
    authFacade = new AuthFacade();
  });

  test('should create', () => {
    expect(authFacade).toBeTruthy();
  });

  test('should return current user', () => {
    jest.spyOn(store, 'select').mockReturnValue(of(mockUser));

    authFacade.currentUser$.subscribe((user) => {
      expect(user).toEqual(mockUser);
    });
  });

  test('should return auth state', () => {
    jest.spyOn(store, 'select').mockReturnValue(of(true));

    authFacade.isAuth$.subscribe((isAuth) => {
      expect(isAuth).toBe(true);
    });
  });

  
});
```

auth-facade.service.ts

```
import { inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Select, Store } from '@ngxs/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { login, signOut } from '../../../store/auth/auth.actions';
import { User } from '../../../store/auth/auth.models';
import { AuthSelectors } from '../../../store/auth/auth.selectors';


@Injectable()
export class AuthFacade {
  
  @Select(AuthSelectors.getCurrentUser) currentUser$!: Observable<User>;
  @Select(AuthSelectors.isAuth) isAuth$!: Observable<boolean>;   

  private store = inject(Store)
  Login(username: string, password: string){
    return this.store.dispatch(new login(username = username, password = password));         
  } 
  
  SignOut() {
    return this.store.dispatch(new signOut());
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the way to solve the issue: you have to add to your tsconfig.spec.json the following code:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    ....,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": false,

  },
```

Comment: my man! I had this exact error and it was driving me crazy. It would be great if you could add more details about where you found it, and why it happens.